# How to solve a matrix PDE and stop solving when solution becomes singular?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerics, singularity

> My question consists of two parts:
>
> 1. How do I get mathematica to solve a PDE Matrix system and plot the result? See below for the PDE matrix system. (By plot the result I mean plot the region where the solution $\Theta$ is nonsingular.)
> 2. How do I stop the integration when the solution matrix becomes singular? I know that away from $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$ the solution matrix $\Theta$ will become singular how do I stop Mathematica from trying to solve pass this point?

The PDE matrix system I am trying to solve is
\begin{align}
\lambda \Theta(x_1,x_2)&=\dot{\Theta}(x_1,x_2)+\Theta(x_1,x_2)A &\quad \text{Equation}\\
\Theta(0,0)&=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -\frac{1}{2} -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ 
1 & -\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{pmatrix} &\quad \text{Initial condition}
\end{align}
I have specified the values of $\dot{\Theta}(x_1,x_2),A,\lambda$ in the block below:

```
(* Definitions *)
A = {{-(x1^2 - 1), -2 x2 x1 - 1}, {1, 0}}
lambda = {{1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}, {Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}}
(*Value of theta for x1=x2=0 *)
ThetaInit = {{1, -1/2 - Sqrt[3]/2}, {1, -1/2 - 1/(2 Sqrt[3]) + 
    2/Sqrt[3]}}
(*Derative of Theta in terms of t. Note \
\frac{dtheta}{dt}=x1'(t)\frac{\partial theta}{\partial x1}+x2'(t) \
\frac{\partial theta}{\partial x2} *)
ThetaDot = ( -(x1^2 - 1) x2 - x1) D[Theta[x1, x2], x1] + 
  x2 D[Theta[x1, x2], x2]
```

Note the initial condition is satisfied as

```
lambda.ThetaInit == ThetaDot + ThetaInit.A /. {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 0}
```

yields true.

**Notes**

- If you need any clarification please feel free to ask.
- This problem comes from https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/9793/42916380-MIT.pdf?sequence=2 I am trying to reproduce the simulation in Mathematica see pages 64-66. I did not share this before because the details are fairly confusing.
- There was an error in the PDE I corrected that error.
- Because people where confused $$\dot{\Theta}(x_1,x_2)=( -(x_1^2 - 1) x_2 - x_1) \frac{\partial \Theta}{\partial x_1}+ x_2 \frac{\partial \Theta}{\partial x_2}$$

Comment: How do you calculate $x_1'(t)\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x_1}+x_2'(t) \
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x_2}$?

Comment: Over what region in `{x1, x2}`do you wish a solution, and what are the boundary conditions for this region?  It seems unlikely that specifying `Theta[0, 0]` is sufficient.

Comment: Unless, that is, you wish only solutions lying along a characteristic curve passing through `{0, 0}`.  Please clarify.

Comment: `lambda.ThetaInit == (ThetaDot + A) /. {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 0}` yields `False`.  In other words, `ThetaInit` does not satisfy the matrix PDE at `{0, 0}`.

Comment: @xzczd $x'_1(t),x'_2(t)$ are given in my post. $\frac{\partial \Theta}{\partial x_1}$ is a matrix. $\Theta$ is what needs to be solved.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I have added the source of where this problem has come from to answer your questions.

Comment: @bbgodfrey There was an error in my problem. I have corrected it and the initial condition holds. For boundary conditions and such from pg. 65 in the text where this problem comes from: "The nonlinear eigenvector field Θ can be computed recursively by solving numerically [PDE system] along system trajectories. The result is illustrated in [Figure], where when stopped integration at the singularities of Θ." I hopes this clarifies your questions.

Comment: If you mean the `-(x1^2 - 1) x2 - x1` and `x2`, I think it's better to show them in $\LaTeX$ form, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question requests solutions for a first-order, linear, homogeneous partial differential equation.  Standard procedures are available in the literature, which we follow here.

**Characteristics**

Solutions propagate along characteristics of the PDE.  As suggested in comments embedded in the code in the question, characteristics satisfy `{x1'[t] == -(x1[t]^2 - 1) x2[t] - x1[t], x2'[t] == x2[t]}`, where `t` is a parameterization of the characteristics.  (In this case, `x2` also could be used as the parameter, but doing so is a bit less convenient.)  The characteristic equations can be solved symbolically to yield,

```
FullSimplify[DSolveValue[{x1'[t] == -(x1[t]^2 - 1) x2[t] - x1[t], x2'[t] == x2[t]}, 
    {x1[t], x2[t]}, t], t \[Element] Reals]
(* {(C[1] (-2 BesselK[1, E^t Sqrt[C[1]^2]] + BesselI[1, E^t Sqrt[C[1]^2]] C[2]))/
    (Sqrt[C[1]^2] (2 BesselK[0, E^t Sqrt[C[1]^2]] + BesselI[0, E^t C[1]] C[2])), E^t C[1]} *)
```

There are two branches to this expression, the first of which reduces to

```
s1 = {(-2 BesselK[1, E^t C[1]] + BesselI[1, E^t C[1]] C[2])/
    ( 2 BesselK[0, E^t C[1]] + BesselI[0, E^t C[1]] C[2]), E^t C[1]};
p1 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Table[s1 /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 10^i}, {i, -3, 5}], {t, -4, 4}, 
    PlotRange -> {-3, 3}, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {x1, x2},
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}];
```

and the second to

```
s2 = {(2 BesselK[1, E^t C[1]] + BesselI[1, E^t C[1]] C[2])/
      (-2 BesselK[0, E^t C[1]] + BesselI[0, E^t C[1]] C[2]), E^t C[1]};
p2 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Table[s2 /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 10^i}, {i, -3, 5}], {t, -4, 4}, 
    PlotRange -> {-3, 3}, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {x1, x2},
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}];
```

Solutions are symmetric about the origin, as is evident from the characteristics equations.  Therefore, solutions with `x2 < 0` are obtained by replacing `s1` and `s2` by their negatives in the code above.  The four plots together provide the total set of characteristics.

```
Show[p1, p2, p3, p4]
```

[image]

Several separatrices are evident, and `{0, 0}` is an equilibrium point (also as noted in the report referenced in the question).  The characteristics can, of course, also be computed by numerical integration of the characteristic equations.  For instance,

```
NDSolveValue[{x1'[t] == -(x1[t]^2 - 1) x2[t] - x1[t], x2'[t] == x2[t],
    x1[0] == 3, x2[0] == -.12}, {x1[t], x2[t]}, {t, 0, 5}];
tst = ParametricPlot[%, {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {x1, x2}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}]
```

yields a curve corresponding almost precisely the the `Red` curve mostly in the lower right quadrant of the plot above.

**Solutions along Characteristics**

Solutions of the PDE can  be obtained from `lambda.theta == D[theta, t] + theta.a`, integrated along characteristics.  (`thetaDot` in the question can be obtained from `D[theta, t]` by the chain rule, if desired.)  If `theta` is represented as

```
theta = {{theta11[t], theta12[t]}, {theta21[t], theta22[t]}}
```

then the equations needed by `NDSolve` are obtained by

```
eqth = Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[lambda.theta == D[theta, t] + theta.a]];
inth = Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[(theta /. t -> 0) == thetaInit]]
```

Expressions for the characteristics obtained above then can be inserted into `a`, and the equations integrated.  However, it is simpler to integrate the characteristic equations and the theta equations simultaneously.  For instance,

```
vars = Flatten[{{x1[t], x2[t]}, theta}];

tmax = 5.7; 
sol = NDSolveValue[{{x1'[t] == -(x1[t]^2 - 1) x2[t] - x1[t], x2'[t] == x2[t], 
    x1[0] == 0.01, x2[0] == .01}, eqth, inth}, vars, {t, 0, tmax}];
ParametricPlot[sol[[1 ;; 2]], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {x1, x2}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}]
Plot[Evaluate@sol[[3 ;; 6]], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLegends -> {theta11, theta12, theta21, theta22}, 
    AxesLabel -> {t, th}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}]
```

[image]

[image]

There is no sign of a singularity in the solution, either here or for any other parameters I have examined.  Indeed, one would not expect singularities to arise from this PDE, because it is linear in  `theta` and its coefficients are well behaved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it is very comprehensive. I do have a few questions. 1) what is the difference between the p1,p2,p3,p4 plots? Different initial conditions or something else? I want to reproduce the plot in your answer to make sure I understand them, but I cannot reproduce `show[p1,p2,p3,p4]` if I don't know the difference between different p.

Comment: 2) If you change `tmax` to a sufficiently large value (in my testing `tmax \approx 20`) $\Theta_{12},\Theta_{22}$ diverges to infinity. From pg 65 in the text: "The nonlinear eigenvector field Θ can be computed recursively by solving numerically [PDE system] along system trajectories. The result is illustrated in Figure... Also note that in the plot we have saturated Θ (which becomes infinite) at the boundary of the eigenvector field." My question is can I tell mathematica to stop integration when Θ   becomes saturated?

Comment: @AzJ  `p3` is obtained by replacing `s1` by `-s1`, and `p4` by replacing `s2` by `-s2`.  I shall add `s2` to the answer for clarity.  I too can obtain solutions for theta that diverge to infinity, but only when `x1` or `x2` also diverge to infinity.  I presumed that you were not seeking such cases.  If you have found a solution that diverges for finite `x1` and `x2`. please send me the initial conditions for `x1` and `x2`, so that I can take a look.  Thanks for thoroughly examining my answer.

Comment: pg 64 of the text provides a different example of the same type of problem where the solution diverges for finite $x_1, x_2$. In trying to reproduce the example on page 65 I was hoping to better understand what the authour meant by singular $\Theta$. Could you should how to do the solution by characteristics part with `thetaDot` in the question can be obtained from `D[theta, t]`.

Comment: Also is there a way to tell Mathematica to stop solving after a certain condition is meet? That was one question that was implied in my initial post that I wanted to get answered.

Comment: @AzJ  You can obtain `thetaDot` from `D[theta, t]` by the chain rule, namely `D[theta, t] = D[theta, x1] x1'[t] + D[theta, x2] x2'[t].  With respect to your second comment, NDSolve` stops automatically when it encounters a singularity.  To stop it sooner, use `WhenEvent`.  Run `NDSolveValue[{{x1'[t] == -(x1[t]^2 - 1) x2[t] - x1[t], x2'[t] == x2[t], x1[0] == -1.8, x2[0] == 1}, eqth, inth}, vars, {t, -5, 7}]` to see `NDSolve stop by itself.  Note that this case corresponds to `x1` approaching infinity.

Comment: I appreciate your answers to all my questions. I have awarded you the answer and bounty.

Comment: @AzJ  Thank you very much.  It is an interesting problem.